# media_gallery images are not opening with proper size

Tags: javascript, media

I have set up a media_gallery with colorbox in http://www.mountvilleresorts.com/. The gallery is working fine, but gallery images are shown very small.

[image: screenshot]

After opening the images again, they are shown in the right size.

What is wrong with galleries that shows the images with a wrong size?

Answer (score 0):

For the images to be of same size on every refreshing of page:-

1. you need to define the image style as per your requirement by Configuration > Media: Image Styles
2. Add the new style by giving it a name
3. Add the effect you want to give
4. Click on Add button and add the corresponding properties.
5. Update the style
6. Finally when uploading the images,choose the image style for the image ,this would result in the constant size of the image throughout instead of the variable size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your JS and CSS aggregation settings in admin/config/development/performance of your config pages. Try turning off all aggregation, clear all caches and see what happens - see if that improves the situation.

Another thing to try would be to try different themes as I know of a case in the past where there have been conflicts (not that common). The specific example I remember is mapping with bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 0):

Please try any other jquery plugin to show the images.For e.g . Lightbox2,fancy-box etc.

Also set the image style in media page for this gallery .